# How to present a modal Login screen using ViewModel First navigation in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog

So I am using the [FreshMVVM](https://codemilltech.com/xamarin-forms-viewmodel-first-navigation-library/) Xamarin.Forms library so I can do ViewModel-first navigation in xamarin. My research tells me that this is a highly recommended practice, yet there seem to be not a whole lot of tutorials for this.

What I am trying to achieve is a login page that pops up as a modal once the user opens the app if they are not signed in.

I have [modified the demo project](https://github.com/DeveloperACE/codemill.vmfirstnav) slightly by adding the modal display button and associated `Command` from the ViewModel to the first page, however, I am **having trouble invoking this programmatically**.

Here is what I am trying to so along with the relevant `Command` code that I intend to tweak to work with a Login Page:

```
public NormalOneViewModel()
{
    if (/*user is not already logged in*/) {
        //display the login page as a modal to get the users credentials and log them in
        //see below
    }   
}
...
ICommand _navToChild;
public ICommand NavigatePopup
{
    get
    {
        if (_navToChild == null)
        {
            _navToChild = new Command(async () =>
            {
                await _navService.PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>();
            });
        }
        return _navToChild;
    }
}
```

This `Command` is invoked via `<Button Text="Show Modal" Command="{Binding NavigatePopup}"/>` in the view associated with the viewModel above.

I have:

- tried to call the command programmatically using `NavigatePopup.Execute(null);`. This fails with an error explaining that the key cannot be found.
- tried to call the command programmatically using `NavigatePopup.Execute();`. This yields the following error: [image: https://imgur.com/a/Hk7k1]
- tried using the custom `NavigationService` that I have set up for this app by calling the `await NavigationService.Instance.PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>();` line from the constructor of the detail page's ViewModel. This tells me that I need to make the method async. Additionally, don't really understand xamarin async too well since I am fairly new to Xamarin.Forms and C#
- `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());` seems to work, but only in the contractor of the code-behind of the MasterDetailPage. this is also using the `Navigation` Class which is apparently [built-into xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal). but this method only accepts a `Page` and doesn't really conform to my ViewModel-First navigation strategy.

What I am primarily wondering is **how do I programmatically invoke a modal (for a login page) when using ViewModel-first patterns?**

**EDIT 1:** I am using Visual Studio for Mac

Apologies for the really confusing setup.

Comment: You command method doesn't receive anythig. Why are you passing `null` ?

Comment: @Greggz when I tried `NavigatePopup.Execute();` Visual Studio gave me an error. https://imgur.com/a/Hk7k1

Comment: I edited the question to include more information

Comment: Have you tried this `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());` .. I dont understand why are u doing `PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>`

Comment: What does this `<NormalModalViewModel>` even mean ? What are you trying to acomplish

Comment: `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());` gives the error that the `await` keyword can only be used on async functions. As for `PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>` that came from the original demo of the NuGet package (https://github.com/codemillmatt/codemill.vmfirstnav). I am tweaking ther demo project to see if this is possible before transplanting the to my main project, at which point I will change it to something like `PushModalAsync<LoginPage>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167525/discussion-between-developerace-and-greggz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so first off, apologies for the confusion regarding the way I presented this and why I was using `PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>` in I wanted to display a Login page. The reason for this is I was trying to modify the sample code in the repositories linked in the question in order to see how I would do this before transplanting it into the project I am working on.

## My Solution

After tinkering with this for quite a while, I realized that the reason `.Execute();` was failing when I was calling it from the constructor with the `key not found` error was **because I was calling it from the constructor**. Even after separating the navigation command into a separate method instead of using a lambda (see below) and calling *that* from the constructor wouldn't work because, from my understanding, the page **hadn't been displayed yet** and my `NavigationService` therefore hadn't registered it or something.

```
ICommand _loginNav;
public ICommand NavigatePopup
{
    get
    {
        if (_loginNav == null)
        {
            _loginNav = new Command(async () => await NavigateModalLogin());
        }
        return _loginNav;
    }
}

async Task NavigateModalLogin()
{
    await _navService.PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>();
}
```

while using `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());` did *work* for me when calling it from the constructor, it wasn't using my custom navigation and I didn't really like that. So I continued looking for a better way.

Considering my realization from earlier that doing this check in the constructor wasn't going to work, I had the idea to use the `OnAppearing()` and `OnDisappearing()` methods provided by the `Page` class in Xamarin.Forms.

However, since I am using ViewModel-first navigation, the processing of the login would need to be done in the ViewModel. So I wrote this in the code-behind of the page to effectively pass the execution to the ViewModel so I could use it:

```
protected async override Task OnAppearing()
{
    await viewmodel.OnAppearing();
    base.OnAppearing();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*****Here*****");
}
```

Then in the ViewModel I had the `OnAppearing()` method call the `NavigateModalLogin()` function from earlier (yes I know this can be optimized to avoid the extra method call but whatever).

The good part about this is that the `OnAppearing()` method is an *Event Handler* in Xamarin. Which means it supports `async`. Which means I didn't have to figure out how to start off an `async`/`await` chain or however that works.

### Tl;dr

Use the event handlers that Xamarin provides to call the same method that the command does (the event Handlers can be either synchronous or asynchronous).

**Code:**

In the code-behind for your page:

```
protected async override Task OnAppearing()
{
    await viewmodel.OnAppearing();
    base.OnAppearing();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*****Here*****");
}
```

in the ViewModel for your page:

```
internal async Task OnAppearing()
{
    await NavigateModalLogin();
}

ICommand _loginNav;
public ICommand NavigatePopup
{
    get
    {
        if (_loginNav == null)
        {
            _loginNav = new Command(async () => await NavigateModalLogin());
        }
        return _loginNav;
    }
}

async Task NavigateModalLogin()
{
    await _navService.PushModalAsync<NormalModalViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: I use a InitAsync in my abstract BaseViewModel. This calls after the load occurs also.