# C# Xamarin Android - Automatically call Login command on app start

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, lifecycle

I have a ViewModel with a LoginCommand (B2C MSAL) which is bound in the corresponding View (Android Platform). The command gets exectued when I press the Login button on the LoginView (which is also the start view when the app starts). I would like to automatically login when the app starts. 
The login xaml is a CustomContentPage.

Where should I call the LoginCommand? In the MainActivity in the OnCreate function? Can someone think of a good approach how to tackle this? If necessary I can post code, but this is more or less a theoretical problem.

Kind regards

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/

Comment: You could refer to the links below. It would be helpful.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48634/from-login-page-to-main-page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480702/how-to-present-a-modal-login-screen-using-viewmodel-first-navigation-in-xamarin